# PDO - Putting all sql data into an html table using prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, phpmyadmin

I want to fetch all the data from my table and display it in an html table but I'm not sure how to do with a prepared statement that will protect me from sql injection.

I've read that it should look something like:

```
$getPlayers = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Player WHERE name = :name");
```

But I'm not sure how to use the method using 'WHERE' to get all my data from the database.

This is my code so far. It works and gets me all my data but I dont think its secure from sql injection, is it?

```
$getPlayers = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Player");
$getPlayers->execute();

$players = $getPlayers->fetchAll();

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Games Played</th><th>Tries</th></tr>";


foreach( $players as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['games_played']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['tries']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Injection is only a problem where user-entered data needs to be sent to your database. 
A query like `SELECT * FROM Player` includes no user data. It's entirely safe from SQL Injection for that reason.

In fact, in this case, there's no benefit in using a prepared statement. A prepared statement  here will make two calls to the database when one will do.

You can do this:

```
$getPlayers = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Player");
foreach ($getPlayers as $player) {
  // do something
}
```

No preparation, no binding, and just one call to the database.

Answer (score 0):

SQL injection uses submitted data. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection for examples. I dont see any usage of submitted data in your example.

If you want to search by name, then the text that is searched can be a sql injection but given
the fact that you will use bind parameters it will not be a issue.

```
$search  = $_GET['search'];
//mysql injection danger:
$getPlayers = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Player WHERE name = '$search'");
```

//because i can search for the string *' OR 1=1 OR 1='*

```
//binded, no mysql injection
$search  = $_GET['search'];
$getPlayers = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Player WHERE name = ?");
$db->bindParam(1, $search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php for more info on binding.

Comment: SQL injection can be caused by *any* invalid content, it doesn't have to come from user input.

Comment: @BillKarwin a malformed query doesn't really qualify as injection.

Comment: @BillKarwin If a sql injection doesn't have its origins from user input like get, post, cookiers, referrer whatever, then it's a feature and not malicious intent

Comment: @CharlieS i think what BillKarwin is saying is that anything that is touched by user input should be escaped. You may do a proper INSERT INTO tbl SET field=:name but later on you fetch the data from tbl into $somevar and execute a select query directly like SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE field='$somevar'. Inserting data blindly also accounts for xss problems.

Comment: Yes, you can definitely have a string in the database that contains single-quotes for example, and if you fetch it from the database and the subsequently use it in a query, you have to escape it or use a query parameter. Likewise any content you get from a file or a web service, etc.